# Making folder that will be accessable in jar

Tags: java, swing, file

I want an option that when ever user selects autologin option...My program will make a folder and it will save a file in it...when the program will start it will look for folder and than file inside it. Problem is when i run my code via netbeans it is running perfectly but when i run it through jar it do not find any folder. Any body can guide me, what is best way to make a folder at run time and access it.
Down is my file writing code...

```
private void writeSerializableUserObject(boolean isAutoLogin , boolean isAutoRemember){
    SerializableUser serializeUserObj = new SerializableUser();
    serializeUserObj.setUserEmail(TempSessionUser.getTempUser().getEmail());
    serializeUserObj.setUserPassword(TempSessionUser.getTempUser().getPassword());
    serializeUserObj.setUserName(TempSessionUser.getTempUser().getF_name());
    serializeUserObj.setIsAutoLogin(isAutoLogin);
    if(isAutoRemember){
        serializeUserObj.setIsAutoRemember(true);
    }
    System.out.println("in side method.......");
```

**Edit**

```
    String path = System.getProperty("user.home");
    File file = new File(path+"/user.ser");
    if(!file.exists()){
          file.mkdir();
    }
    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutPut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        ObjectOutputStream oos;
        try {
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutPut);
            oos.writeObject(serializeUserObj);
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }//Inner catch statment end

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }//Outer Catch statment end
}
```

After editing it is giving me this exception...within netbeans execution.her uptill HaseebAimal is my home directory path

```
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\HaseebAimal\UserData\user.ser (Access is denied)

    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:194)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:145)
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using `URL url = getClass().getResource("/UserData");`, I think it would be better to use `System.getProperty("user.home")` which will return the users "home" folder.  The problem MAY be related to you not having write permissions with the folder you are executing your application...

Comment: @MadProgrammer please review the edit.

Comment: @NishantShreshth you can see now what error i am getting.

Comment: `File file = new File(path+"/user.ser");
    if(!file.exists()){
          file.mkdir();
    }` You are creating a directory instead of a file. It should rather be `File file = new File(path+"/user.ser");
    if(!file.exists()){
          file.getParentFile().mkdir();
    }`

Comment: As Guillaume has pointed, you are creating a directory named `path+"/user.ser"`, which is not what you want.  In connection to with what Guillaume has suggested, you should also be checking to see if the directory creation failed...`if(file.exists() || file.getParentFile().mkdir()) { ... } else { System.err.println("Failed to make output directory"; }`

Comment: @GuillaumePolet thanks for your suggestion i have tried it but still getting same exception. I think main problem is "Access Denied" how can i overcome it.

Comment: @HaseebWali There should be no need to call `file.mkdir()`.  The `home` directory should already exist.

Answer (score 2):

`getClass().getResource("/UserData")` gives you a location in the class path which sometimes (usually) isn't a directory in the file system. Instead, you should probably pick one or more of:

- Prompt the user for a save location.
- Use a default location of some file or folder in the user's home directory, which you can get with `System.getProperty("user.home")`.
- Save it in the current working directory, which you can get with `System.getProperty("user.dir")`.

The last option is probably the worst unless you *know* what the working directory will always be because you've handled the installation of your app in some way.

Comment: `file.mkdir()` creates a directory named `user.ser`, and then you try to write to it as a file. That doesn't work. With a `FileOutputStream`, the file will be created if it doesn't exist anyway, so the `exists()` check is unnecessary unless you want to take some action if the file is already there. Note that an existing file will be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Before creating the `FileOutputStream` check what do `file.canRead()` and `file.canWrite()` return.

You need to make sure that the application *can* write to the location. If you do not have access to the location, try changing the directory to something else where you have write access.

Something like:

```
String path = "D:/test";
```